# Wireless keeps asking for password

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I just installed 12.04 on my old ibook G3 (Since I wiped the HDD)

Now luckily I have a WiFi Ethernet bridge on my PC to give the ibook Internet. But even when it is connected to `eth0` (LAN) it keeps asking to connect to `eth1` (Wi-Fi)
the router is using `WPA2` Personal with `AES`

I was just wondering, because the router is upstairs and the ibook is downstairs next to my PC. and the WiFi connects upstairs, but I can't use it up there cos the battery is junk and I got no plugs that'll reach.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Edit Connections [network connections]
2. Delete all existing wired and wireless connections
3. Reboot
4. Connect to wireless network and enter password
5. Fixed!

The reboot is necessary, didn't work for me until I rebooted.

Comment: your answer is correct but you shouldn't have to delete any wired connections.

Comment: Yes, just delete the wireless you're trying to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

What i did was open the connection (Edit Connections), opened the one i use (Edit...), and in the Wireless Security did:

- enter the Key (which used to be here, but after upgrade miraculously disappeared);
- checked Available to all users.

now it works fine. i have no idea why the problem even occurred.

Comment: By "key", you mean the WPA or WEP key/password right?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and it seems that my roommates ISP is blocking me. Details at question "Internet Service Provider only supports Microsoft OSes" This answer seems to be useful and I am trying it out. Perhaps it will work for you.

> You might be helped by the Firefox extension [User Agent
>   Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)
>
> Then if a website asks what you're running, Firefox can disguise
>   itself as Internet Explorer running on a Windows machine. Though, if
>   the website requests something like ActiveX (a feature of only IE),
>   Firefox will not be able to process the request.

[Answered by Sepero](https://askubuntu.com/a/158975/22949)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on a 32 bit system using an Anthros AR9285 wireless driver.
The wireless would boot up perfectly fine. After a while the wireless would disconnect, 
then continue to ask for my password but never connecting again.
My system log (/var/log/syslog) was constantly reporting network errors.
I had to either reboot, or suspend the system to get it to work again.

It was interesting because, I had a previous 12.04 install on the same machine,
which worked just fine. The problem started after I did a fresh 12.04 install.
The new install had the linux-generic kernel.

The problem stopped after I installed the linux pae kernel.
There is some really good documentation about pae here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

You can install the pae kernel: 
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae

This is an extremely frustrating problem and hope this solution
may help.

Answer (score 0):

I could not connect to anything and was asked for password every 30 seconds.
Went to Edit Connections and deleted the wired and wireless connections completely, rebooted and re-entered the password and now works OK.
At last I have the same Ubuntu working on my PC and laptop, and will hopefully be able to be free of Windows in the near future!

Answer (score 0):

My wi-fi was working fine and all the sudden I got the same problem on ubuntu 12.04 (desktop) and fedora 17 (laptop), at the same time. Using Windows 7 I could establish wifi connection, but with some problems. My wifes laptop with Windows 8 established connection with no problems.

Soft router restart solved the problem.