# Century Link ISP only supports Microsoft OSes

Tags: networking, internet

I'm trying to set up my computer to run through my roommates ISP, when I initially get online I have to go through his ISP's set-up process, when I get to the end of the process it tells me that it only supports microsoft OSes. Sometimes I get kicked off randomly or can't get on at all.

I'm new to ubuntu or any linux OS for that matter and don't have any windows software and can't afford any right now.

Is there some software that I can download to get around this or some settings that I can change or something?

I've already searched this site and haven't found any previous questions to help me with this, though I did learn a few things. Any information will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which ISP? Link to website? City, country, etc? Please describe the set-up process in **as much detail** as possible, since we can't see what's going on.

Comment: ISP is Century Link. It didn't bring up the set-up process today... yet... so I don't remember any questions. I just click the "Next" button 2 or 3 times then it tells me that my OS isn't supported. I'll take some notes the next time it happens, but for now I'm going to try the User Agent Switcher below. Thanks.

Comment: Century Link also supports Macs, so it should be able to support Linux just fine.  However, they almost certainly won't have an easy setup program for Linux, so you'll need to get the information you need from someone in support (or by e-mail) and enter it yourself.  Believe me, it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be helped by the Firefox extension [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher)

Then if a website asks what you're running, Firefox can disguise itself as Internet Explorer running on a Windows machine. Though, if the website requests something like ActiveX (a feature of only IE), Firefox will not be able to process the request.